# How do I find max values in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I Have an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2003
                    [date] => 2010-09-15 13:27:35
                    [status] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2004
                    [date] => 2010-09-18 13:27:35
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2004
                    [date] => 2010-09-18 13:27:35
                    [status] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2003
                    [date] => 2010-09-12 13:27:35
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2004
                    [date] => 2010-09-18 13:27:35
                    [status] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2004
                    [date] => 2010-09-18 13:27:35
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2004
                    [date] => 2010-09-18 13:27:35
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [product] => 2004
                    [date] => 2010-09-18 13:27:35
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )
```

I want to "collapse" each second dimension array and obtain the max DATE value and the max status value.So the first index would return 2010-09-18 13:27:35 and '6' etc.

The problem is further complicated by the empty array in the last index. I would like to use this empty array and report it as the MAX date and status.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the result?

Comment: Do you retrieve this array from a db request or a webservice or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking everybody. I figured it out.

```
$date=array();
$status=array();
$availability=array();
    foreach($set as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach($value as $value2)
        {

            if(isset($value2[1]))
            {
            $date[$key][]=$value2[1];
            $status[$key][]=$value2[2];

            }
            else
            {
            $date[$key][]='2022-09-18 13:27:35';
            $status[$key][]='0';
            }

        }


                $availability[$key]=array(max($date[$key]),min($status[$key]));

     }
```